# Пользовательские классы исключений

Tags: python

У меня есть шахматный симулятор в виде кучи функций. Для каждого хода я запрашиваю у пользователя через `input()` его ход, который передаю в функцию `move()`. Внутри этой функции есть куча проверок на корректность ввода(король не может ходить на две клетки/ладья не может ходить по диагонали/...), и если проверка не проходит я вызываю различные исключения(в зависимости от того какая проверка).
Вопрос в следующем - есть ли смысл писать пользовательские исключения чтобы сделать код более читаемым? Не представляю какое исключение поднимать в случае, когда сам себя подставляешь под мат или пытаешься съесть свою фигуру.

Comment: Совсем не обязательно вызывать какие-то исключения. Можно делать обычную проверку через if

Comment: «какое исключение» — `BadMoveError` на всё сразу, чё мудрить-то)

Comment: @andreymal BadMove это не ошибка, это просто плохой игрок :) А вот InvalidMove уже другое дело.